# Ruby on Rails - N to N relation, weird values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

im using rails 3.2.3 and am gettign weird values in my app.

I have 2 models, a user and role, which are a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. The middle table is created with role_id and user_id column and correct name (roles_users).

The thing is, when I assign a user to a role (upon creation through a checkbox) and then view all the users with roles associated to them I get invalid role id(like 75216410 when it sould be just 1 or 2) and the role name is just "Role" instead of admin.

I want to use Devise and CanCan, I've set up Devise but this thing keeps me from going.

My roles and users controller has the traditional restfull actions, the exact same ones we get when we scaffold. And since the DB values are correct, I believe this isn't the issue.

My models are:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Devise modules
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :registerable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  #relationships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  #nested attr
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles

  # Accessible (or protected) attr
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids

  # attr_accessible :title, :body


  #validations
  validates :username, :presence => true
  validates :username, :email, :uniqueness => true

end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  attr_accessible :name, :user_attributes, :role_id

end
```

My users and roles views are the same you would get by a scaffolding as well.
My users index:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.username %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.roles.id %></td>    #should display "1"
      <td><%= user.roles.name %></td>  #should display "admin"
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The thing is, this displays, instead of the role id (1), some random number like 69067380. If I refresh, this number changes to another random number. As for the Role name, it always says "Role" instead of "admin".
This reminds me of a pointer memory address, but i doubt it is the case.

NOTE: When I check the tables with MySQL workbench, everything is fine and all the values in the tables are correct.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You user has many roles so when u fires `user.roles` it will give an **array** instead of single record try `user.roles.first` or `user.roles.first.try(:name)` it display first role.you can iterate role and display them as per your requirement.

Comment: Seems like I am confused about relations after all.
Maybe a 1 to many would be better, but anyways, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `user.roles.id` is the id of the relation itself. You should select one of the roles, by using `user.roles.fist.id` or something. One user can have many roles, you propably want to print them all, with a cycle.